# Split Layout with responsive page?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to design a page in which half-left portion of the viewport for Login & other half-right portion of the viewport for Signup i.e with split layout(side by side in tablet,desktop, and large screen & stacked(top for login & Bottom for Signup after reaching within a mobile width range) in mobile, and lower devices). I made this with two col-md-6 (one for Login & another for Signup) with `100vh` for min-width:`768px` and above and with `50vh`  for max-width:`768px` devices(means in mobile devices it display as stacked) and below. I made this code but after size testing(by scaling browser window) I am facing problem(on scale down) like Login portion(i.e. Half-left) height take size as the login form. I have not given any specific width & height of any div(Because bootstrap handle it automatically using grid system). I am giving the code so that you can help me.

## I Want this Output(Actually I get it with small flaw)

**[Sample-in-mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Boo2V.png)**
**[Sample-in-Computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctghl.png)**

## Problem:

**[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4nP1.png)**

```css
/*index.css*/

body {
  padding-top: 56px;
}

.tmbl-nav {
  background-color: #001427;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}


/*.left-side,.right-side{
    height:50vh;
    width:100%;
}
*/

.left-side {
  background-color: #BF0603;
}

.right-side {
  background-color: #8D0801;
}

.form-box {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
}


/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and down) */

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .nav-link {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .left-side,
  .right-side {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!--index.php-->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/index.css" />
  <title>My Web Site</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?php include_once("inc/header.php");?>
  <!--navbar for navigation-->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="left-side col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center align-items-center">
              <div class="form-box-top text-center text-light">
                <h2>Login Now</h2>
                <p>Enter Username & Password to Log on.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-box rounded">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputUName" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUName" aria-describedby="userName" placeholder="Username" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPsword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPsword" aria-describedby="password" placeholder="Password" />
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-side col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center align-items-center">
              <div class="form-box-top text-center text-light">
                <h2>Register Now</h2>
                <p>Fill in the below form to get instant access.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-box rounded">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputFName" class="sr-only">Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFName" aria-describedby="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Email" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputMobile" class="sr-only">Mobile</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputMobile" aria-describedby="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" aria-describedby="password" placeholder="Password" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputCPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputCPassword" aria-describedby="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row text-dark">
                    <label for="checkYesNo" class="col-auto pt-0 col-form-label">You have Reference ID:</label>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" />
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="inlineRadio1">Yes</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" />
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="inlineRadio2">No</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputREmail" class="sr-only">Reference Email ID</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputREmail" aria-describedby="referenceEmail" placeholder="Referral Email ID" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group text-dark">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkTC" />
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkTC">
                                                        I Agree all the Terms & Condition
                                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- JQuery,then Popper.js, then Bootstrap.min.js -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/indexnavigation.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Rohit, Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

just remove the following code present in your CSS, That should fix it.

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
      .left-side,
      .right-side {
        height: 100vh;
      }
    }
```